# C++ Makefile doesn't seem to apply `g++` optimization flags

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, c++20

I have been using the following Makefile, which was passed down to me, to compile C++ code.

```
CXX := g++-11

CXXFLAGS := -std=c++20 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fopenmp -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wold-style-cast -Wshadow -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wdisabled-optimization -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Wformat-overflow -Wformat-truncation -Wundef -fno-common -Wconversion -fdiagnostics-show-option -fdiagnostics-color=auto -Wuninitialized -Wno-unused-function -fstrict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-parameter -Wcast-align -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Woverloaded-virtual -Wmisleading-indentation -Wduplicated-cond -Wduplicated-branches -Wlogical-op -Wnull-dereference -Wuseless-cast -Wdouble-promotion
CXXFLAGS += -MMD -MP

LDFLAGS := -L
LDLIBS := -lm -lrt -lpthread

SANITIZER := -fsanitize=address,leak,undefined
CXXDEBUG := -g -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fanalyzer -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC
CXXRELEASE := -DNDEBUG -O2

MAKEFLAGS := -j

SRC := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ := $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
DEP := $(SRC:.cpp=.d)
DEBUG := $(SRC:.cpp=.dbg)
RELEASE := $(SRC:.cpp=.rel)

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(DEBUG) $(RELEASE)

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), clean, install) # don't create .d for clean and install goals
-include $(DEP)
endif

%.dbg:%.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXDEBUG) $(SANITIZER) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

%.rel:%.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CXXRELEASE) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ) $(DEP) $(RELEASE) $(DEBUG) *~ *.out *.dbg *.rel compile_commands.json *.d
```

The Makefile seems to automatically scan for all modified .`cpp` files, and compiles each one into a debug build and a release build with file type `.dbg` and `.rel`, respectively.
However, I recently have noticed that the optimization flag `-O2` in `CXXRELEASE seems to not be applied to the release build. I found this out when I realized that compiling the code through just the command` g++-11 -std=c++20 -O2 main.cpp` resulted in an executable that was an order of magnitude faster than the .rel produced by make.

Can anyone figure out what is wrong with this Makefile? I am pretty confused right now, because I have been using this for years, and I never realized or noticed this problem until
a few days ago.

Comment: What command exactly do you actually see get ran with your Makefile?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica  I just use `make -s`

Comment: That's the opposite of what you should do when trying to debug a Makefile problem.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I've also tried adding debug prints under the `%.dbg:%.o` and for `$.rel:%.o`, and it seems to be compiling with all the flags. However, the resulting `.rel` file doesn't seem to be optimized. Strangely enough, if I just copy-paste the equivalent command directly into the terminal, the optimization happens. No idea why.

Comment: Without even looking at the makefile, I'd add `-r` to the flags to disable builtin rules.

Comment: As a guess I'd say the problem is that both `.dbg` and `.rel` depend on `.o`: so which command do you expect to be run to generate that `.o`?  Your `CXXDEBUG` and `CXXRELEASE` flags are only ever used when linking.

Answer (score 0):

> I have been using the following Makefile, which was passed down to me, to compile C++ code.

[...]

> I am pretty confused right now, because I have been using this for years, and I never realized or noticed this problem until a few days ago.

Let that be a cautionary tale about the need to understand your tools.

> Can anyone figure out what is wrong with this Makefile?

Ordinarily, nearly all optimization is performed during compilation from source files to object files.  This makefile does not provide any optimization options for this stage of the build.  Moreover, it uses the same object files to support the `.dbg` executables as it does to support the `.rel` executables, and as long as it does so there's limited room for those executables to be meaningfully different from each other.

You could conceivably build separate debug and release object files, the latter with the wanted optimizations.  However, given that the makefile builds only programs whose entire source is in a single file, it would be easier to skip the `.o` files altogether and build straight from source to executables.  If any past version of this file successfully did what it seems intended to do, then that's probably how it did so.

The primary changes to go (back) to such a version would be to change the prerequisites of the `%.dbg` and `%.rel` rules:

```
%.dbg: %.cpp
        # ...

%.rel: %.cpp
        # ...
```

Since you will no longer be building object files, you probably should also remove `$(OBJ)` from the list of files to clean, and perhaps not define that variable at all.